# Command line to remontly shutdown the display and power on

Tags: screen, command-line

I'm using a digital signage CMS and app to control an Android tablet with root access. I can "reboot" it with this simple command, but I haven't found a command line to put the display to sleep(shut down / on).
I'm thinking it's possible also to set shutdown hours and start up?

Comment: Please don't mix shutdown and sleep together. They are neither interchangeable nor synonymous to each other. If you just want to turn off the display or put the phone to sleep (akin to using a timeout in Android devices or pressing power button once), use adb keyevents. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events. If you intend to shutdown the phone (turn off the OS and hence, the device itself, not just the display), then use `svc` command. Cold Booting the device automatically is not something I know of.

Comment: As for timers for shutdown, many automation apps can do this.